# Laravel Relationships 2 tables

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables which I want to connect,

```
First table = Friendship
ID
User1 = Tim 
User2 = Johny
Accepted = 0/1 <- friends if accepted = 1

Second table = Rooms
ID
Owner 
Room_ID
Roome_name
```

My goal is to get all Johny friends then check if any of them has Rooms if yes retrieve owner, room_id, room_name. I searched result in google but I could not find it. It's my first time with relationships and I don't know how to use where statments there. I would be greateful for simple and clear advice.

Here are my classes:

```
class Friendship extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'friendship';

    public function friendrooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Room');
    }
}

class Room extends \Eloquent {    
    protected $table = 'rooms';

    public function roomowner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Friendship');
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a users table, you'd want to use your friends table as a pivot table for users onto itself.  It sounds quite complicated, but it ends up being pretty easy in practice...

I modified a few of your columns because there were a few things that didn't make a lot of sense.  Not sure why `rooms` needed an id column and a room_id column.  This should get you a pretty good base and it's hopefully fairly extensible for you.  You'd probably want a `room_user` table which stores who is in what room.

## Migrations

```
Schema::create('friends', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('friend_id');
    $table->boolean('accepted');
    $table->boolean('deleted');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('rooms', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');  // The is room's owner.
    $table->string('description');
    $table->integer('room_id');
    $table->string('room_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

## User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id')->wherePivot('accepted', '1');
    }

    public function room()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Room');
    }

    public function hasRoom()
    {
        return (bool)$this->room()->count();
    }
}
```

## Use

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->friends as $friend) {
    if($friend->hasRoom()) {
        echo "<a href='javascript:location.href='ts3server://localhost/?port=9987&cid=".$friend->room->room_id."'>Join ".$friend->room->name."</a>";
    }
}
```

If you need anymore help, ask away.

Edits:

If someone can have many rooms, simply change that relationship to a `hasMany()`.  Then you would have to use it just a bit differently...

```
$user = User::find(1);
    $friends = $user->friends()->paginate(15);

foreach($friends as $friend) {
    if($friend->hasRoom()) {
        foreach($friend->rooms as $room) {
            echo "<a href='javascript:location.href='ts3server://localhost/?port=9987&cid=".$friend->room->room_id."'>Join ".$friend->room->name."</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

The logic for the 3 rooms per day doesn't really belong here.  That would be more of a validation issue when allowing them to create rooms.

Comment: Hey, my room needs room_ID beacuse it's other ID from other database I am using teamspeak 3 api framework and when user is creating room the server query give the room ID, and I need this id for invite link. I am making notification system for when friend is creating room and that Room_id is needed for this linkjavascript:location.href='ts3server://localhost/?port=9987&cid=<room_id goes here> So when user click it he goes to friends channel :)

Comment: Oh cool, I added those back in and modified what it outputs so it should output the links for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's all the beauty in the `Eloquent`. You don't have to put a `where` in no place!! You just call something like

```
$friends = Friendship::find($friend_id);
$friends->friendrooms()->get(); //To get a list of all rooms
```

... yes, it's ***that simple***!

The second you put a `belongsTo` or `hasMany`, the Eloquent already tells Laravel it should perform one kind of operation on the query: `where id = 'child_id'` and `where = foreign_id = "id"`, respectively. I don't know if I have made myself clear. Any doubts, just comment! =D